# Uri scheme "file" trouble: obtain file size, open PDF in external viewer, and open an inputstream (compared to scheme "content")?

Tags: android, pdf, uri, dropbox, url-scheme

<***See important EDITs below***>

When I open an PDF in my app the supplied uri can be of 2 schemes: "file" and "content":

- Using Dropbox: *file:///data/data/com.dropbox.android/global/external/docpreviews/test2.pdf*
- Using Google Drive: *content://media/external/file/142*

With "content" all my functionality is working as expected, but with "file" I encounter some trouble:

1. I have no clue how to obtain the file size of the PDF.
2. Opening the PDF in an external PDF viewer results in an error like "could not open file" (no matter if this is dropbox, Google Drive or any other app).
3. Opening an inputstream (to convert the PDF to a byte[]) also causes trouble: FileNotFoundException.

A possible solution would be to convert "file" to "content", then I'd be very happy. I've been searching for it for a while, but cannot find out how, so I guess that's not possible. So how to solve these 3 problems?

My AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.PdfActivity"
....
  <intent-filter android:label="Open PDF">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In PdfActivity I collect the Uri:

```
uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)
```

1) Then obtain filesize:

```
switch (uri.getScheme()) {
  case "file":
    // How to get the filesize here?
     break;
  case "content":
    // Get filesize using cursor
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaColumns.SIZE}, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    size = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.SIZE));
    cursor.close();
    break;
}
```

2) Opening the PDF in an external viewer with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

try {
  startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  // Show dialog: no PDF viewer on device
}
```

3) Convert PDF to byte[] using inputstream:

```
public byte[] getByteArrayFromPdf(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        switch (uri.getScheme()) {
          case "file":
            // How to do this?
            break;
          case "content":
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            break;
          default:
            // Something going wrong...
        }
        return getByteArrayUsingInputStream(inputStream);
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITs**: My file is saved in the downloads folder (hence the content-uri from Google Drive).

*getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)* causes the *FileNotFoundException* for the scheme "file". Even though both uri-schemes originate from this same file. This mean that *FileNotFoundException* should result from something else than a file that does not exist.

Apparently it is caused by *libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)*, which makes more sense when I review the uri (file) from Dropbox: it appears dropbox opens the file and saves it in *com.dropbox.android*, in which I do not have access. I guess this explains all the trouble, am I right?

**FINAL EDIT:**
As stated above, it is probably a problem with the privacy of the file made by Dropbox PDF viewer app, because with Adobe (and other apps, which also result in an uri with "file") I don't have any trouble: *new File(uri.getPath()).length()* gives me the file size and receiving an inputstream works the same as with "content" uri's.

**But this gives me a new question:** is it possible for me to: opening an external PDF file (eg. downloads map) using the Dropbox app, 'Send PDF' to open it in my app, and then somehow have access to this file so I can read the size, open it in another PDF viewer, AND convert it to inputstream?

ps. are other uri-schemes possible when opening a PDF in my app in this way?

Answer (score 0):

> I have no clue how to obtain the file size of the PDF

Call `getPath()` on the `Uri`. Wrap that path in a `File` object, and call `length()` on the `File` object.

Or, replace your existing code with `DocumentFile`. Use `fromSingleUri()` for the `content` scheme and `fromFile()` for the `file` scheme. Then, call `getSize()` on the `DocumentFile`.

> Opening the PDF in an external PDF viewer results in an error like "could not open file" (no matter if this is dropbox, Google Drive or any other app).

The other app has no rights to the content. You can attempt to transfer rights by adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`.

> Opening an inputstream (to convert the PDF to a byte[]) also causes trouble: FileNotFoundException.

You do not show the code that is giving you this exception. `openInputStream()` supports `file` and `content` schemes, so use that for both cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, non of that works: 1) File.length(), returns *0*. When using documentFile, then *fromSingleUri* returns *null* (and I guess you mean .length() on the DocumentFile instead of size()?) ...
2) The flag doesn't make a difference ... 3) I used openInputStream for "file", which caused the FileNotFoundException (I clarified my post describing that). At east the last solution should work, maybe the Exception gives us a hint? Maybe it really doesn't exist at that uri? Well, I opened that *same* PDF with both PDF viewers (one gives "file", other "content"), so that shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @PKuijpers: The `Uri` that Dropbox is giving you is one that you cannot access, due to some bug in their app. "is it possible for me to..." -- you are certainly welcome to implement an `ACTION_SEND` `<intent-filter>` on an `<activity>` to receive PDF files, if that's what you mean... but you already have that. So, try that flow and see what you get from your chosen PDF viewer app. Note that not all PDF viewers may offer a "share" option. "are other uri-schemes possible when opening a PDF in my app in this way?" -- sure. `http`, `https`, `android.resource` are three.